# webpack TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolved' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, storybook

I'm currently working on a project with webpack (version `5.50.0`) and Storybook (version `6.3.7`). The `stories` directory in this project is **within** the `storybook` directory.

During an update of webpack to version `5.51.1` I came across the following error
when I run `npm run storybook`:

```
10% building 0/15 entries 21/55 dependencies 1/17 modules/Users/dsudol/development/projects/ca_projects/Test/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:816
        if (entry.resolved !== undefined) return entry.resolved;
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolved' of undefined
    at getResolvedTimestamp
```

Here's my `main.js` config

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    './**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'
  ],
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5'
  },
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    '@storybook/addon-contexts/register',
    '@storybook/addon-controls',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-essentials',
      options: {
        backgrounds: true
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

How can I solve this **without** moving the `stories` out of the storybook directory or using an explicit path like `'./stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'`.

**Tipps to Reproduce**

Create a simple app with react (I did it without `npm install create-react-app`), webpack and Storybook. Move the `stories` directory inside the `.storybook` directory. Then change the path in `main.js` accordingly and run `npm run storybook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Webpack `5.51.2`, so you'll need to update.

Further reading:

- [Bug Report](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14028)
- [Bug Fix](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/14030/commits/0088d5565c602fd28cd6145186a95ed08f119642)

Comment: Thank for the answer! This has solved the issue!